# multiple string comparing in switch

Tags: c#

have a requirement in C# switch in string compare.

```
string result = getResponse();
switch (result)
{
    case "S0": ret = "true";
               break;
    case "S1": ret = "fail";
               break;
    // ? can be any digit number, ex, M:0, M:100, M:1000
    case "M:?": ret = result;
               break;                 
    default: ret = "wrong";
               break;
}
```

how to make the switch statement in "M:?" case?

Comment: With a switch, you can't. In the `default` case, you can check `result.StartsWith("M:")` or a regex compare.

Comment: You need the `if` statement, for your case, exactly!

Comment: got it, make the comparing in default section

Comment: Note that C# 7.0 is still out of reach to many developers (due to software limit), so the general solution for this is just combine the default case with `if` to check for some remaining cases.

Comment: @KingKing if the question is about legacy C# then the question needs to be tagged appropriately.

Comment: @KeithNicholas C# 6.0 and earlier versions are not ***legacy***, they are still inherited.

Comment: @KenChu I'm not clear if with the `"M:100"` example if you want `"M:100"` or `"100"` returned?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option instead of using switch pattern matching is to handle more complex case in the default bloc with if statements like so

```
string ret = string.Empty;
string result = getResponse();
switch (result)
{
    case "S0":
        ret = "true";
        break;
    case "S1":
        ret = "fail";
        break;
    default:
        Regex rgx = new Regex(@"^M:\d+");
        if (rgx.IsMatch(result))
        {
            ret = result;
        }
        else {
            ret = "wrong";
        }
        break;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are using C# 7, you can use [switch pattern matching.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/pattern-matching)

```
string ret = string.Empty;
string result = getResponse();
switch (result)
{
    case "S0":
        ret = "true";
        break;
    case "S1":
        ret = "fail";
        break;
    case var val when new Regex(@"^M:\d+").IsMatch(val):
        ret = val;
        break;
    default:
        ret = "wrong";
        break;
}
```

As @KingKing commented in the question that many devs does not have luxury of using C# 7, at that time you can use following code :

```
string result = getResponse();
switch (Regex.IsMatch(result, @"^M:\d+") ? "M:XXX" : result)
{
        case "S0":
            ret = "true";
            break;
        case "S1":
            ret = "fail";
            break;
        case "M:XXX": // make it unique so that it will not collide with other case statement and update this value in ternary condition accordingly
            ret = result;
            break;
        default:
            ret = "wrong";
            break;
}
```

Comment: @downvoter : Care to comment so that I can improve my answer.

Answer (score 1):

try with pattern matching :-

```
        public string Convert(string result)
        {
            switch (result)
            {
                case "S0": return "true";
                case "S1": return "fail";
                case var m when Regex.IsMatch(m, @"^M:\d+$"): return m;
                default: return "wrong";
            }
        }
```

if you are using an older C# without pattern matching, move your clause to before the switch

```
        public string Convert(string result)
        {
            if(Regex.IsMatch(result, @"^M:\d+$")) return result;
            switch (result)
            {
                case "S0": return "true";
                case "S1": return "fail";
                default: return "wrong";
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about using LINQ:

```
var switches = new Func<string, string>[]
{
    x => x == "S0" ? "true" : null,
    x => x == "S1" ? "fail" : null,
    x =>
    {
        var match = Regex.Match(x, @"^M:(\d+)");
        if (match.Success)
            return match.Groups[1].Captures[0].Value;
        return null;
    },
    x => "wrong",
};

string result = "M:47";
string ret = switches.Select(s => s(result)).Where(r => r != null).First();
```

That gives me `"47"` for `ret`.